Agnosting Learning Algorithm for Squared Loss Regression and Conditional Density Estimation
In the lecture notes titled "Foundations of Reinforcement Learning and Interactive Decision Making" by Foster and Rakhlin, it is mentioned in the Proposition 1 that there exists an algorithm that's excess risk under squared loss, when competing against the function class $\mathcal{F}$, given $n$ samples from the data distribution $D$, is upper bounded by $\log(\mathcal{F}/\delta)/n$ with probability at least $1-\delta$. I wanted to know what that algorithm was, and where I can find the source of this result.

Is there a proof of Prop 1 given? Presumably the algorithm is empirical risk minimization (ERM). Such proofs generally use a concentration bound to prove that each function in the class has empirical loss close to its true expected loss, then union-bound over the hypothesis class. Any theoretical ML text such as Understanding ML, Foundations of ML will have proofs along these lines.

@usul There is a proof given realizability; however there is not one when the assumption is dropped. Yet the proposition states the bound still holds without the assumption.
